# How to send two query into one? Is there any other alternative?

Tags: mysql

So I have this query that gets me the number of failed parts in the order. for example 94 failed. However, I want to see the total amount of parts in that order. For example, 94 failed and 200 total. How can I achieve that in one query? If it's not possible how can I combine two queries in one result table?

```
SELECT status, COUNT(order)
FROM result
WHERE status='failed' and order = '4373'
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: Can you post the CREATE TABLE script please?

Comment: I am not creating any tables. Just want to see the response from the select statment.

Comment: I mean the CREATE TABLE script for the result table

Comment: We'll also need some test data to work with

Comment: I am not sure that I got your request right. I am just sending this query to the DB using DBbeaver and I see the reasult of the query in the bottom window. I am not creating tables thus I don't have the script for creating them.

Comment: Kashan you must know the structure of the table you are querying right? Could you post that?

Comment: very simpe table which has two column one called status and the other called order.the status can be failed or passed and some order numbers.

Comment: @Kashan Please run the query `SHOW CREATE TABLE result` and add the output to your question. The information provided there will help us answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL (as the question tagged):

```
SELECT SUM(status='failed') AS failed_orders, COUNT(1) AS total_orders
FROM result
WHERE order = '4373'
-- GROUP BY status -- ??
```

For another DBMS (for example, for Microsoft SQL Server):

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN status='failed' THEN 1 END) AS failed_orders, COUNT(1) AS total_orders
FROM result
WHERE order = '4373'
```